# setting to unblock installation of applications from PC

Tags: 2.2-froyo, installation, htc-wildfire

I am starting android application development, and connected htc wildfire, started its sync software. And clicked on `Application Installer`. And it gives following errror message:

```
your phone is set to block installation of applications not sourced in android market
```

So I want to know that what settings can I change to unblock installation of applications from my pc. And from eclipse. I actually want to test applications developed by me.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable `Unknown sources` in the android settings (on my device it is in the `Security` section). Also enable `USB debugging` in `Developer options`.